# using forest, pdflatex and having issues with overlapping nodes and filling lower split nodes

Tags: pdftex, forest

My code using forest package and compiling with pdflatex works fine for narrow text and upper parts of split nodes. Please provide your forest based input to

1.) avoid overlaps in nodes with wider text. I assume wrong use of

```latex
before computing xy={s/.average={s}{siblings}}
```

2.) access the lower part of split nodes. When trying

```latex
[narrow\\text 1\nodepart{lower}text, splitRec, draw, before computing xy={s/.average={s}{siblings}}]
```

pdflatex generates the error:

```bsh
! Missing \cr inserted.
```

Code:

```latex
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}


\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usepackage{flexisym}
\usetikzlibrary{svg.path}


\forestset{
    qtree/.style={for tree={fit=band, parent anchor=south, child anchor=north, align=center, inner sep=3pt}},
    splitRec/.style={rectangle, rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2, draw}
}


\begin{comment}
     :compile using pdflatex
\end{comment}


\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}, baseline, qtree, forked edges
        [start\\node, ellipse, draw
    [first\\diamond, diamond, draw
        [second\\diamond, diamond, draw, edge path'={ (!u) |- (.parent)} % 
            [, phantom] % phantom node left so that the subsequent child has a node leaving the parent on the west
            [third\\diamond, diamond, draw, s sep+=0.25cm, edge path'={ (!u) |- (.parent)}
                [, phantom]
                [narrow\\text 1, splitRec, draw, before computing xy={s/.average={s}{siblings}}]
                [forth\\diamond, diamond, draw, edge path'={ (!u) |- (.parent)}
                    [, phantom]
                    [narrow\\text 2, ellipse, draw, before computing xy={s/.average={s}{siblings}}]
                    [fifth\\diamond, diamond, draw, edge path'={ (!u) |- (.parent)}
                        [, phantom]
                        [wide text 3\\Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing\\elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut\\labore et dolore magna aliqua ut enim ad minim veniam\\quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip\\ex ea commodo consequat duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit, rectangle, draw, before computing xy={s/.average={s}{siblings}}]
                        [sixth\\diamond, diamond, draw, edge path'={ (!u) |- (.parent)}
                            [, phantom]
                            [wide text 4\\Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing\\elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut\\labore et dolore mag    na aliqua ut enim ad minim veniam\\quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip\\ex ea commodo consequat duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit, rectangle, draw, before computing xy={s/.average={s}{siblings}}]
                            [, phantom]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
        [narrow\\text 0\\right below, rectangle, draw, before computing xy={s/.average={s}{siblings}}]
        [, phantom]
    ]
]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

.pdf:
[image]

Comment: There seems to be no predefined migration path from superuser to tex.se. Either flag "in need of moderator intervention" or delete it here and ask a new question on tex.se (the later is probably faster and easier)

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat That answer is rather outdated now and could be done much more efficiently with current Forest.

Answer (score 3):

The overlaps are easiest to avoid by letting `forest` do its job of avoiding them. In this case, this means omitting `fit=band`. We can easily get the desired extra space (between, e.g. children of the first diamond) by a larger `s sep`. (See the comments `increase/decrease the horizontal distance between children` in the code.)

Specifying nodeparts in the OP's code does not work because of the `align` key used by the `qtree` key defined in the preamble.  This key differs from the `tikz` key with the same name. It works by inserting the content in a `tabular` environment. Inside it, `\nodepart` makes no sense, thus the `Missing \cr` errors.

The solution is to use `tikz`'s `align` key on multipart nodes (or to manually create the tabular environment for each text part), which is achieved by `/tikz/align`. The `\nodepart` command in the content then works as intended, see `narrow text 2` node. (By the way, the second part of `rectangle split` is called `two`, not `lower`.)

A bit of `forest` candy.

- `nodepart` style defined in the preamble lets you write `nodepart={nodepart name}{text}`, see `narrow text 1` node.
- Styles for specific nodeparts can be easily defined, see the definition of `part two` and its usage in `wide text 3`.
- `nodeparts` style parses the content into parts using an arbitrary separator. Even `\\` works, see `narrow text 0`. Separating by comma requires the content in braces, see `wide text 4`. For me, a semicolon is usually the best candidate for the separator. How does the `nodeparts` style work?

  - First, it defines styles for specific nodeparts and constructs a temporary keylist starting with `content'` followed by all the defined nodepart styles. This is achieved by `split`ting the given list of nodepart names. In `narrow text 0` it defines nodepart styles `nodepart@two` and `nodepart@three`; the temporary keylist is `content',nodepart@two,nodepart@three`. (A better implementation might pre-compute the temporary keylist (which depends on the shape of the node.)
  - The temporary keylist is used as the third argument of `split option`, which actually splits the content. The keys of the temp keylist and the parts of the content are "zipped": `content'` gets the main part and simply truncates the `content` option to it; `nodepart@two` gets the second part and calls `nodepart={two}{second part of content}` on it, effectively replacing the first separator by `\nodepart{two}`; etc.

The code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usepackage{flexisym}
\usetikzlibrary{svg.path}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}

\forestset{
  qtree/.style={for tree={
      parent anchor=south,
      child anchor=north,
      /tikz/align=center,
      inner sep=3pt,
      s sep=5em,
    }},
  splitRec/.style={rectangle, rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2, draw},
  right below/.style={
    calign with current,
  },
  my diamond/.style={
    diamond,
    draw,
    edge path'={ (!u) |- (.parent)},
  },
  nodepart/.style 2 args={% generic nodepart
    content+=\nodepart{#1}#2,
  },
  part two/.style={nodepart={two}{#1}}, % specific nodepart
  % parse the content into nodeparts:
  nodeparts/.style 2 args={% #1 = part names, #2 = content separator
    tempkeylista'={content'},
    split={#1}{,}{define@nodepart},
    split option/.process=Rw1{tempkeylista}{{content}{#2}{##1}},
  },
  define@nodepart/.style={
    nodepart@#1/.style={nodepart={#1}{##1}},
    tempkeylista=nodepart@#1,
  },
}


\begin{comment}
  :compile using pdflatex
\end{comment}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}, baseline, qtree, forked edges
  [start\\node, ellipse, draw
    [first\\diamond, diamond, draw,
      s sep=30em, % increase the horizontal distance between children
      [second\\diamond, my diamond, 
        [,right below, phantom]
        [third\\diamond, my diamond, 
          [narrow\\text 1, nodepart={two}{text}, splitRec, draw, right below]
          [forth\\diamond, my diamond, 
            [narrow\\text 2\nodepart{lower}text, ellipse split, draw, right below]
            [fifth\\diamond, my diamond,
              s sep=2em, % decrease the horizontal distance between children
              [wide text 3, splitRec, part two={Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing\\elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut\\labore et dolore magna aliqua ut enim ad minim veniam\\quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip\\ex ea commodo consequat duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit}, right below]
              [sixth\\diamond, my diamond, 
                [{wide text 4,Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing\\elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut\\labore et dolore mag    na aliqua ut enim ad minim veniam\\quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip\\ex ea commodo consequat duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit},
                  rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2, nodeparts={two}{,},
                  draw, right below]
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
      [narrow\\text 0\\right below,
        rectangle split, rectangle split parts=3, nodeparts={two,three}{\\},
        draw, right below]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I noticed my personal version of `forest.sty` has changes not yet in the version on CTAN. What's the status of the code at the moment? (And any news on name spaces?)

Comment: (+1) of course, but I really don't like multipart nodes.

Comment: I wish I had more time to work on Forest ...

Comment: That's some beautiful code! Thank's a lot! I am on it, to understand what just happened ... However, I will start with the answer from @cfr since it seems to need less manual adjustments such as `% increase the horizontal distance between children`

Answer (score 2):

Usually, I would use Sašo's code on the grounds that it is certainly better than anything I might dream up. However, I really don't like multipart nodes, so I'd probably do something like this.

[Translation: I'd done most of this before Sašo answered, so I thought I might as well finish.]

- I almost always start on questions like this by removing all manual adjustments, on the grounds that they are almost certainly doing more harm than good.
- I see almost no reason to use multipart nodes, which are known to be buggy even in ordinary `tikzpicture`s, when any Forest node can be a `tabular` with any specification you like.
- Instead, I would adjust set the `inner xsep` to zero and put compensatory space on each side of a centred column, so that an ordinary `\hline` can be used to separate the node 'parts'. I set this to `3pt` and set `inner ysep` to `3pt` so the spacing is consistent with the original intent.
- I use Forest anchors and some conditionals to get the edges to play nicely with the diamonds and so forth.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest,array}
\newcolumntype{C}{@{\hspace{3pt}}c@{\hspace{3pt}}}

\begin{document}
  \begin{forest}, baseline,  for tree={draw, inner xsep=0pt, inner ysep=3pt, fit=rectangle, align=C},
  where n children=0{calign with current edge, for siblings={if n=1{edge path'={(!u.first)-|(.parent)}}{edge path'={(!u.last)-|(.parent)}}}}{}
    [start\\node, ellipse, 
    [first\\diamond, diamond, 
        [second\\diamond, diamond, 
            [third\\diamond, diamond, 
                [narrow\\text 1\\\hline lower part\\of node ]
                [forth\\diamond, diamond, 
                    [narrow\\text 2, ellipse,  ]
                    [fifth\\diamond, diamond,  
                        [wide text 3\\Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing\\elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut\\labore et dolore magna aliqua ut enim ad minim veniam\\quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip\\ex ea commodo consequat duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit ]
                        [sixth\\diamond, diamond,  
                            [wide text 4\\Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing\\elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut\\labore et dolore mag    na aliqua ut enim ad minim veniam\\quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip\\ex ea commodo consequat duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit,  ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
        [narrow\\text 0\\right below, ]
    ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: output 'tree']

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I am on it to understand the code and most certainly may come back for further clarifications; sorry for that.

Comment: line `where n children=0{calign with current edge, for siblings={if n=1{edge path'={(!u.first)-|(.parent)}}{edge path'={(!u.last)-|(.parent)}}}}{}` in my words:

Comment: 1.) when there is 1 child `children=0`, it will be aligned under its parent `calign with current edge`

Comment: 2.) in case of siblings `for siblings`,
2.1) sibling 1 `n=1`' is aligned first sideways then down what results to a left down position in a left to right order
2.2) subsequent siblings are aligned in a standard way as children are aligned what is under its parent
2.3) the last sibling is aligned sideways then down what results to a right down position since left down and center are already taken.

Comment: In my understanding, single children can not be positioned left down or right down; is that correct?

Comment: @wba You could position single children differently. I didn't allow for that partly because I didn't know what mattered and what didn't (and, generally, things look neater and more compact when single children are aligned with parents). The `where n children=0` bit isn't positioning nodes at all. All it affects is the way the edges are drawn between parents and children. The nodes themselves aren't affected.

Answer (score 1):

To my opinion your graph is simpler to draw as pure `tikz` picture:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,
                shapes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance=3mm and 4mm,
    box/.style = {draw, text width=#1, align=center,inner sep=2pt},
    box/.default = 24em,
    dia/.style = {diamond, aspect=1.5, draw, align=center, inner xsep=0pt},
    elp/.style = {ellipse, aspect=1.5, draw, align=center, inner xsep=0pt}
    mpv/.style = {rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2, 
                  rectangle split empty part height=2ex, draw,
                  text width=#1, align=center},
    mpv/.default = 4em
                        ]
% from bottom to top
\node[box]  (n1) {wide text 4\\Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore mag na aliqua ut enim ad minim veniam quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit, rectangle, draw, before computing};
\node (n2) [dia, above=of n1]           {sixth\\diamond};
\node (n3) [box, left=of n2 -| n1.west] {wide text 3\\Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing\\elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua ut enim ad minim veniam quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit};
\node (n4) [dia, above=of n3]           {fifth\\diamond};
\node (n5) [elp,right=of n3.west |- n4] {narrow\\text 2};
\node (n6) [dia, above=of n5]           {forth\\diamond};
\node (n7) [mpv, left=of n6]            {narrow\\text 1};     
\node (n8) [dia, above=of n7]           {third\\diamond};
\node (n9) [dia,above left=of n8]       {second\\diamond};
\node (n10) [dia,above right=of n9.north -| n4]     {first\\diamond};
\node (n11) [box=6em,below=of n10]      {narrow\\text 0\\right below};
\node (n12) [elp,above=of n10]          {start\\ node};
%
\draw   (n12) -- (n10) -- (n11)
        (n10) -| (n9)
        (n9)  -| (n8)
        (n8)  -- (n7)
        (n8)  -| (n6)
        (n6)  -- (n5)
        (n6)  -| (n4)
        (n4)  -- (n3)
        (n4)  -| (n2)
        (n2)  -- (n1)
        ;
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:** I add a node with multi part shape on which I forgot in the first version of the answer.

[image]

Comment: I'm a Forest fan, as you know, but it doesn't lend itself to this one :-).

Comment: Which isn't to say it can't be done :-).

Comment: @cfr, to me is this particular tree simpler to draw with pure `tikz` (i'm not mastered forest yet :-) ), however I hope that someone, who is more skilled in `forest` show, how to do this. In fact, this has already happened!

Comment: Indeed. Twice, in fact. But I think it is really as easy to do in Ti*k*Z. Doing it in Forest is more a 'because it's there' kind of thing :-).

Comment: Thank you for the Ti _k_ Z version. Since the graph is just a twig in a forest full of massive trees, I opt for Forest. @cfr how did you format the italic _k_ in TikZ from your previous comment without ending up with a space between Ti and Z?

Comment: @wba I just put asterisks around the `k`. `Ti*k*Z`.